# Cannot load background images in css

Tags: css, path, frontend, background-image, static-files

I am working to build a site using express as backend and pug as a template engine. I specified all the middlewares needed to render pug in browser.

**Folder outlook:**

**index.js is in same directory as public**

[image]

**Index.js**

```
//Setting public/static files
app.set(express.static,path.join(__dirname,'public'))

//Setting up view engine
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "public/html"));

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home.pug') //Renders home.pug which extends index.pug
})
```

This is how I applied background image in home.css which styles home.pug

**home.css:**

```
.home-container {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/home_bg.jpeg");
}
```

I even used below codes and tried

```
background-image: url("/images/home_bg.jpeg");
```

In both cases I am getting the below error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/images/home_bg.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Did you try adding "." before "/"? It will take you to the root directory then you can set your path. ie:  background-image: url("./images/home_bg.jpeg");

Comment: Yaa, I tried it. any how the get request should be http://localhost:8080/images/home_bg.jpeg but it is returning error instead of a image. Since root is public

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in serving static files.
I used

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
```

instead of

```
app.set(express.static,path.join(__dirname,''public))
```

This solved the problem.